# C++11: std::max(a,b) in static_assert()?

Tags: c++11, constants, assert, constexpr, static-assert

I noticed, that in [24.4.7] of the last C++-Std Doc N3291 `max` ist not `constexpr`:

```
template<class T> const T& max(const T& a, const T& b);
```

Therefore, it is not allowed to use it in a `static_assert` for example. Correct?

```
static_assert( max(sizeof(int),sizeof(float)) > 4, "bummer" );
```

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(int) > 4 || sizeof(float) > 4, "bummer" );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct.

I imagine the reason is simply that `std::max` calls `T::operator<` for an arbitrary type `T` and for `std::max` to be `constexpr`, it would require `T::operator<` to be `constexpr`, which is unknown.

Comment: To remedy that. you can make your own template-only `struct Max<A, B>` to create a static `max`...

Comment: So this implies that template functions/classes that access a member of the template type _cannot_ be `constexpr` ever? That seems silly.  Why is that the standard?

Comment: @MooingDuck It's not. This answer is wrong. It's legal for a `constexpr` function template to only produce constant expressions for some types. (For other types, it simply can't be used in constant expressions.)

Comment: @RichardSmith Could you submit an answer to this question that is correct, then? I see that [the C++14 draft as of 2013-05-15](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) still hasn't marked `min` and `max` as `constexpr`, and this seems like a really simple and useful change. What's the Committee's objection?

Comment: As it seems, like me, you *assumed* that a `constexpr` function would be required to only call other `constexpr` ones. But reading through §7.1.5.(1)-(9) I must agree with @RichardSmith, that it is not. Or can you you point me to why it is, Peter?

Answer (score 2):

This is correct; `std::min` and `std::max` are not `constexpr`, not even in the latest draft of C++14 ([N3690](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)), so they cannot be used within constant expressions.

There is no good reason for this, only bad reasons. The most significant bad reason is that the C++ committee is composed of individuals who have a limited amount of time to work on standardization, and no-one has put in the work required to make these functions `constexpr` yet.

Note [N3039](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3039.pdf), a change to the C++ standard adopted in 2010, that slightly extended the `constexpr` facility specifically so that function such as `min` and `max` could be made `constexpr`.

You can work around this by defining your own `min` and `max` functions:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr const T &c_min(const T &a, const T &b) {
  return b < a ? b : a;
}
template<typename T, class Compare>
constexpr const T &c_min(const T &a, const T &b, Compare comp) {
  return comp(b, a) ? b : a;
}
template<typename T>
constexpr const T &c_min_impl(const T *a, const T *b) {
  return a + 1 == b ? *a : c_min(*a, c_min_impl(a + 1, b));
}
template<typename T>
constexpr T c_min(std::initializer_list<T> t) {
  return c_min_impl(t.begin(), t.end());
}
// ... and so on
```

Comment: I can not totally follow N3039 train of thought -- it sounds like "`const&` is almost `constexpr`", which I find a bit far-going. I would not teach to that my students when explaining `const`-things. Also, I am a bit skeptical about your implied *"C++ is a bad standard because there is no full time paid standardizer"* (*ehem* ;-). I do not have enough insights into the committees works, but I always guessed there are plenty of discussions and and work going on. And third, the point of @peter-alexander still stands, that `operator<` would have to be `constexpr` in general, right?

Comment: @towi Be aware that the change made by N3039 was significantly extended (to allow *arbitrary* reference types to be literal types) before C++11 shipped. We implementors drank the "poison for constant expression evaluation", and it wasn't so bad after all. Your inference that I'm saying that *"C++ is a bad standard"* is incorrect. It is simply a fact that the committee comprises people, and we have a finite amount of time. `operator<` would not need to be `constexpr` in general, because `constexpr` functions are not required to always produce constants.

Comment: I just read through §7.1.5.(1)-(9) and saw with amazement that you are correct about `operator<` would not required to be `constexpr` I can not find a trace of that requirement. I guess I always assumed it. Only that "the arguments must be *Literal Types*" which can fail on instantiation in a template. I wonder about the implications, then. Hrmm... (Yes, I heard about some of the compromises; Herb Sutter is ranting about some, for eg.)  (I hope you saw the twinkly after my inference. I am guessing that implementing `constexpr` was simpler then implementing "the other meta language" templates.)

Answer (score 0):

this works on c++ 11

```cpp
template<const Sz a,const Sz b> constexpr Sz staticMax() {return a>b?a:b;}
```

use:

```cpp
staticMax<a,b>()
```

and of course `a` and `b` must be `constexpr`